# Trying to identify a linear regression model

Tags: regression

I am struggling to understand what to do with variables with t-values that aren't significant. Are there any interactions among the variables? If so, how do I detect them?

```
. reg ChildIQ MotherHS MotherIQ MotherWork MotherAge

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs =   434
-------------+----------------------------------   F(4, 429)     =   29.38
       Model |  38791.1475         4  9697.78687   Prob > F      =   0.0000
    Residual |  141595.009       429  330.058296   R-squared     =   0.2150
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared =   0.2077
       Total |  180386.157       433  416.596205   Root MSE      =   18.168

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ChildIQ |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. 
-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
    MotherHS |   5.561178   2.313455     2.40   0.017     1.014061    10.10829
    MotherIQ |   .5620814   .0607717     9.25   0.000     .4426342    .6815287
  MotherWork |   .1337287   .7676278     0.17   0.862    -1.375051    1.642508
   MotherAge |   .2198599   .3323067     0.66   0.509    -.4332919    .8730117
       _cons |   20.82261   9.187647     2.27   0.024     2.764207    38.88102
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also created dummy variables, but still struggling on how to identify a regression model.

```
. regress ChildIQ i.MotherWork i.MotherHS MotherWork#MotherHS MotherIQ MotherAge

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs =  434
-------------+----------------------------------   F(9, 424)     =  13.82
       Model |  40906.1413         9  4545.12681   Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |  139480.015       424    328.9623   R-squared     =  0.2268
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared =  0.2104
       Total |  180386.157       433  416.596205   Root MSE      =  18.137

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ChildIQ |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. 
--------------------+------------------------------------------------------
         MotherWork |
                 2  |   9.044113   4.939433     1.83   0.068    -.6647108    18.75294
                 3  |   11.54613   6.326508     1.83   0.069    -.8890954    23.98135
                 4  |    5.66136   4.761632     1.19   0.235    -3.697984     15.0207
                    |
         1.MotherHS |     11.465   4.289277     2.67   0.008     3.034109     19.8959
                    |
MotherWork#MotherHS |
               2 1  |   -9.47015    6.05801    -1.56   0.119    -21.37762    2.437321
               3 1  |  -9.194914   7.400503    -1.24   0.215    -23.74115    5.351327
               4 1  |  -6.910289   5.656841    -1.22   0.223    -18.02923    4.208655
                    |
           MotherIQ |   .5436701   .0617836     8.80   0.000     .4222297    .6651104
          MotherAge |   .2237867   .3339276     0.67   0.503    -.4325729    .8801464
              _cons |   17.55475   9.566023     1.84   0.067    -1.247979    36.35749
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for any contribution.